# Auto-community wiki works differently to how I expected

Tags: support, community-wiki

I just witnessed a post get converted to CW for the first time, with the reason  `[made Community Wiki by being edited by more than 5 different editors]`.

Now I knew this was a rule but what surprised me was that it seems to be my rollback that triggered the conversion - and I'd already edited the post previously, and hence wasn't a new "different editor".

I also thought that the original post didn't count as a an edit, but it looks like only 5 other users have edited the post rather than "more than 5".

From [What are community-wiki posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts?rq=1)

> *How does a post become a Community Wiki post?*
>
> - The body of the post has been edited† by at least five (5) different users.
>
> † As far as what constitutes an "edit" for community wiki, only edits to the actual body of the post will count towards automatic community wiki. Edits to the title and tags, as well as rollbacks, do not contribute to automatic wikification. (source)

[Post in question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21776019/revisions) - I edited the question, someone splattered my edit with their own, so I rolled back and merged his into mine.

Can I get any clarification on what happened here?

---

On rereading the above I see that the excerpt from "What is community-wiki?" says "at least five (5) different users", where as the conversion reads " more than 5 different editors".

Is it just the case that the conversion reason should be "at least" as well?