# Rollbacks are counting into auto-wiki when they shouldn't

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-wiki, rollbacks

So I rolled back a poor edit on [Mysticial's branch prediction answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902) and inadvertently turned it into a community wiki:

[image]

Not a big deal, until I realize that [my rollback should *not* have caused it to become a wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151931/have-rollbacks-not-count-towards-community-wikiness). Apparently it's not supposed to and it was never supposed to, at least until now.

So... here's a bug report. In the meantime, <del>I'll leave it as it is and wait for Mysticial to let me know if he wants the wiki status to remain or be removed.</del> [I've removed the wiki because as we all know, Mysticial is a rep whore.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/15297553#15297553)

Comment: The software reacts to a bad edit by making the post easier to edit. What weirdness.

Comment: I think what it is, is that once too many people edit it, it takes another action on the post for the conversion to take place. I raised [a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221121/auto-community-wiki-works-differently-to-how-i-expected) because my rollback caused an auto-wiki even though I had already edited the post before, and in this case I count you as the 7th editor (the message suggests that the 6th editor causes conversion).

Comment: @OGHaza: woulds't be the first [off-by-one bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225055/why-is-this-answer-edited-10x-not-community-wiki) in the CW code..

Comment: Uh? How was that a bad edit? It replaced a bare link by a link with descriptive text.

Comment: No, it merely stripped the URL portion and left the slug, complete with underscore. That's no better than just leaving the bare URL there, and IMO was worse to look at than the bare URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've removed the [automatic conversion of posts to community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217189/remove-the-automatic-conversion-to-community-wiki-when-more-than-5-users-edit-a), not just from multiple editors (which affected this case) but in all situations, editing and otherwise.

Going forward, there are moderator flags that will be automatically raised when a post is edited by at least 10 users. I'm pretty sure that rollbacks are not included in this count, but the raised threshold should also prevent the number of misfires that one might see from this if they are.